# How can i turn off Audience validation for IdentityServer3?

Tags: validation, identityserver3

I had a problem with IdentitiServer3 - there is a need to provide access to it from the outside (different address). Access token is successfully formed, but an error occurs during the validation token:

> JWT token validation error
>   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidAudienceException:
>   IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences:
>   'http://xxx/sas_sas/resources'. Did not match: 
>   validationParameters.ValidAudience:
>   'http://yyy/sas_sas/resources' or
>   validationParameters.ValidAudiences: 'null'

Is it possible to disable this validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PublicOrigin helped to solved this problem. [Documentation](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/deployment.html)

Comment: Sorry, but I coudn't find any place/code example in the given link which explains how to disable audience validation. Did I miss something?

Comment: Hi. You can see some related code [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/1169). Some refs: it doesnt turn off validation, but just give abilility to setup another valid audience. (Excuse me for my english)